# solving logarithmic equations by expressing in terms of exponents

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is it ***always*** valid to solve logarithmic equations by raising both sides as powers of a common base? 
 
 As in: $$ln(x) = ln(y) $$$$ e^{ln(x)} = e^{ln(y)} $$$$ x = y $$$$ where \quad x,y ∈ \mathbb{R}>0 $$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exponential function is a bijection from $\mathbb R$ to $(0,\infty)$ hence yes.